# How to refresh the runOnUiThread that is inside a thread every 5 seconds?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

```
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                data ="";

                    String splithis;
                 splithis=mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                 splited = splithis.split(" ");
                course = splited[0];
                sections = splited[2];
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        data = bw.getAttendanceFromDB(term, course,sections,day);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                ArrayList<Properties> attendanceusers = attendanceUse(data);
                                addAttendance(attendanceusers);                     
                            }
                        });   
                    }
                }).start();
            }
```

I have ArrayList attendanceusers that populates my dynamic design, it is getting the attendance of students in the database and populating my design dynamically. However whenever another students come in, it doesn't reflect the change dynamically. The refresh is happening if im clicking another date, but what i want is for it to refresh for every 5 secs or 10 secs. im trying to research the answers here in stack but all the answers are different from mine.

Comment: there is no runOnUiThread(new Runnable() in your suggestion of duplicate

Comment: what i am searching for is the refresh on runOnUiThread

Comment: Is this Android or something else? Eclipse is used to develop all sorts of Java, you need to tell us exactly which framework / GUI you are working with.

Comment: This is android sir :)

Comment: What part of your code requires to be ran on the UI thread? What's wrong with the duplicate that you can't add that if you really need it?

Comment: Also, what happens when you choose one item, then another? Do you want both Runnables to be adding items to the adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to run something in a thread every 5 seconds, you can add it wherever you want.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        data = bw.getAttendanceFromDB(term, course,sections,day);
    }
}, 0, 5 * 1000);

handler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ArrayList<Properties> attendanceusers = attendanceUse(data);
        addAttendance(attendanceusers);  
    }
})
```

You can take that out of the click listener, and have it run once.

Don't forget to call `timer.cancel()` when your activity is paused, and then re-running that when it is resumed().